# How to implement a fast, queryable and persistant database in phantomjs?

Tags: node.js, sqlite, phantomjs, browserify

I have been using phantomjs for doing some heavy lifting for me in a server side `dom` environment. Till now I have been putting by data structures in-memory (i.e. doing nothing special with them) and everything was fine.
But recently under some use cases i started running into following problems:

1. memory usage becoming too high making swap to kick in and seriously effecting my performance.
2. not being able to resume from the last save point since in-memory data structures are not persistent (obviously)

This forced me to look for a database solution to be used on phantom but again I am running into issues while deciding on a solution:

1. I don't want my performance to get too effected.
2. it has to be persistent and queryable
3. how do i even connect to a database from inside phantom script.

Can anyone guide me to a satisfactory solution?

**Note:** I have almost decided on `sqlite` but connecting to it from phantom is still an issue. Nodejs provides `sqlite3` node module, i am trying to `browserify` it for phantom.

**Note Note:** Browserify didn't worked! Back to ground zero!! :-(

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 9):

Phantomjs' filesystem API allows you to read and write binary files with:

```
buf = fs.read(FILENAME, 'b') and
fs.write(FILENAME, buf, 'b')
```

sql.js (https://github.com/kripken/sql.js/) gives you a javascript SQLite
implementation you can run in phantomjs.

Combine the 2 and you have a fast, persistent, queryable SQL database.

Example walkthrough

1. Get javascript SQLite implementation (saving to /tmp/sql.js)

   $ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kripken/sql.js/master/js/sql.js -O /tmp/sql.js
2. Create a test SQLite database using the command-line sqlite3 app (showing it is persistent and external to your phantomjs application).

   sqlite3 /tmp/eg.db

   sqlite> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, created  INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

   sqlite> .quit
3. Save this test phantomjs script to add entries to the test database and verify behaviour.

$  cat /tmp/eg.js

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    sqlite3 = require('./sql.js'),                                                                    
    dbfile = '/tmp/eg.db', 
    sql = 'INSERT INTO test(id) VALUES (NULL)', 
    // fs.read returns binary 'string' (not 'String' or 'Uint8Array')
    read = fs.read(dbfile, 'b'), 
    // Database argument must be a 'string' (binary) not 'Uint8Array'
    db = new sqlite3.Database(read),              
    write,
    uint8array;                                                                                       

try {   
    db.run(sql);
} catch (e) {
    console.error('ERROR: ' + e);                                                                     
    phantom.exit();                                                                                   
}

// db.export() returns 'Uint8Array' but we must pass binary 'string' to write
uint8array = db.export(); 
write = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, Array.prototype.slice.apply(uint8array));                     

fs.write(dbfile, write, 'b');                                                                         
db.close();                                                                                           

phantom.exit();
```

4. Run the phantomjs script to test

   $ /usr/local/phantomjs-2.0.0-macosx/bin/phantomjs /tmp/eg.js
5. Use external tool to verify changes were persisted.

   sqlite3 /tmp/eg.db

   sqlite> SELECT * FROM test;

   id          created

   1           2015-03-28 10:21:09

   sqlite>

Some things to keep in mind:

1. The database is modified on disk only when you call fs.write. 
   Any changes you make are invisible to external programs accessing the same SQLite    database file until you call fs.write.
2. The entire database is read into memory with fs.read. 
   You may want to have different OS files for different tables -- or versions of tables -- depending on your application and the amount of data in the tables, to address the memory requirements you mentioned.
3. Passing what is returned by sqlite3.export() to fs.write will corrupt the    SQLite database file on disk (it will no longer be a valid SQLite database file). 
   Uint8Array is NOT the correct type for the    fs.write parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Writing a binary data in phantomjs works like this:

`var db_file = fs.open(db_name, {mode: 'wb', charset: ''});
db_file.write(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, db.export()));
db_file.close();`

You have to set the charset to `''` because otherwise the writing goes wrong.